# Writing an expression using logic

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Write an expression using letters $\land, \lor, and$ $\neg$ which has the following truth table:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
P&Q&R&???\\ \hline
T&T&T&F\\
T&T&F&T\\
T&F&T&F\\
T&F&F&T\\
F&T&T&T\\
F&T&F&F\\
F&F&T&F\\
F&F&F&F
\end{array}
$$

How would you in general solve for ??? I was told there is a mechanical way of doing it but I don't see it.

Comment: [Here are instructions and examples about making tables](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5044/25554)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll get you started. Look at the last column of the truth table: you want your statement to be true when

$$P\text{ is true and }Q\text{ is true and }R\text{ is false}\tag{1}$$

$$\mathbf{OR}$$

$$P\text{ is true and }Q\text{ is false and }R\text{ is false}\tag{2}$$

$$\mathbf{OR}$$

$$P\text{ is false and }Q\text{ is true and }R\text{ is true}\;,\tag{3}$$

and for no other combination of truth values of $P,Q$, and $R$.

Is there a simple statement that’s true exactly when $P$ and $Q$ are true and $R$ is false? Sure: $$P\land Q\land\neg R\;.$$

Now find a similar statement that is true exactly when $(2)$ is true, and another one that’s true exactly when $(3)$ is true. Once you have these three statements, how should you combine them to get what you want?

Comment: I am able to derive the logic statement for each row but having trouble putting them together. I tried many times and in each case something goes wrong. So do you derive for ??? using only the ones for the True statements?

Comment: @Eames: Yes. You have three statements, which I’ll call $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$, and $\varphi_3$, and you want a statement that is true when at least one of $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$, and $\varphi_3$ is true. What connective can you use where I have $\oplus$ to give $\varphi_1\oplus\varphi_2\oplus\varphi_3$ this property?

Comment: Each statement has at least one $\lnot$ to make the statement true. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Eames: No, you’re looking for a way to combine $\varphi_1$ (i.e., $P\land Q\land\neg R$), $\varphi_2$ (i.e, $P\land\neg Q\land\neg R$), and your third statement into a single statement that’s true when at least one of $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$, and $\varphi_3$ is true.

Comment: @Eames: Be sure to note the use of **OR** in my answer.

Comment: Oh I see the connection your making now. So for the first two true statements would simplify to $(P\land \lnot R)$ $\lor$ $(\lnot P \land Q \land R)$, correct?

Comment: @Eames: The first parenthesis should contain $P\land Q\land\neg R$, but yes, you want to connect the three individual conjunctions with $\lor$ to make $\varphi_1\lor\varphi_2\lor\varphi_3$.

Comment: After staring at it for a moment, was able to simplify it further.

Answer (score 2):

There are exactly three rows which evaluate to "true = $T$".

We can take the first row, and see that $P \land Q \land \lnot R$ evaluates true.

Doing this with each row, we get that the truth table evaluates true when:

$$(P \land Q \land \lnot R) \lor (P \land \lnot Q \land \lnot R) \lor (\lnot P \land Q \land R)$$

This method gives you disjunctive normal form. And it is possible that it might be simplified. But this conveys precisely what the truth table conveys.

Comment: SO very nice +1

Comment: $+1$ and many $\small{+}^{\large{+}}$${+}^{\large{+}}$

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods available to solve this.  One method that's fairly easy for smaller circuits is to use a [Karnaugh Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).  It requires a bit of study in order to understand what functions will look like on the map, but it makes the task fairly easy after Karnaugh maps are understood.

A second way is using the following trick:
We know that $x \lor y \lor z$, read "x or y or z", will have only one false value, and the rest will be true.  So you can substitute $P$, $Q$, $R$ or their negations, $\overline{P}$, $\overline{Q}$,or $\overline{R}$ into this to get one false value and seven true values.  Then you can essentially "paste" functions like this together to get the result.

For example, "(not $p$) or (not $q$) or (not $r$)" gives the truth table:

T
T
T
T
T
T
T
F

Then, "(not $p$) or (not $q$) or ($r$)" gives the truth table:

T
T
T
T
T
T
F
T

...and combining them gives : "((not $p$) or (not $q$) or (not $r$)) *and* ((not $p$) or (not $q$) or ($r$))":

T
T
T
T
T
T
F
F

...We can proceed in this fashion mechanically to slowly add one false value until we reach the desired function.

Answer (score 0):

Entered by truthtable:

```
??? = P' Q R + P Q' R' + P Q R';
```

Minimized:

```
??? = P R' + P' Q R;
```

Related Karnaugh-Veitch map as screenshot from KVD Pro:
[image]